# Infer value of one column based on other column values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If running speed of a day is > 0, its status is true.

In case of no data for a particular day, infer last status code (another
column in table) value recorded and if the value is zero then mark run status as true. For codes other than zero mark status as false.

See the table below

```
Day       Run speed Statuscode  Status  
---------------------------------------
1-Jan-14    55         0        TRUE  
2-Jan-14    60         0        TRUE  
3-Jan-14    58         0        TRUE  
4-Jan-14    61         0        TRUE  
5-Jan-14    57         0        TRUE  
6-Jan-14    56         0        TRUE  
7-Jan-14    60         0        TRUE  
8-Jan-14                        TRUE  
9-Jan-14                        TRUE  
10-Jan-14   55         0        TRUE  
11-Jan-14   56         0        TRUE  
12-Jan-14   60         0        TRUE  
13-Jan-14    0        20        FALSE
```

(example 8-jan-14/9-jan-14 does not have value but since 7th was last recorded and it was true that is why the status of those two dates are true as well)

Comment: You posted requirements, but you forgot to include your work and a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `OUTER APPLY` as more flexible lag

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4c73f/18

```
select 
    o.*,
    Status = 
        convert(bit,
            case 
                when o.RunningSpeed > 0 
                or   o.RunningSpeed is null and prev.StatusCode = 0 then 
                    1
                else 
                    0
            end)    
from tbl o
outer apply
(
    select top 1 StatusCode
    from tbl i
    where i.Day < o.Day and i.StatusCode is not null
    order by i.Day desc
) prev
```

Output:

```
|                  Day | RunningSpeed | Statuscode | Status |
|----------------------|--------------|------------|--------|
| 2014-01-01T00:00:00Z |           55 |          0 |   true |
| 2014-01-02T00:00:00Z |           60 |          0 |   true |
| 2014-01-03T00:00:00Z |           58 |          0 |   true |
| 2014-01-04T00:00:00Z |           61 |          0 |   true |
| 2014-01-05T00:00:00Z |           57 |          0 |   true |
| 2014-01-06T00:00:00Z |           56 |          0 |   true |
| 2014-01-07T00:00:00Z |           60 |          0 |   true |
| 2014-01-08T00:00:00Z |       (null) |     (null) |   true |
| 2014-01-09T00:00:00Z |       (null) |     (null) |   true |
| 2014-01-10T00:00:00Z |           55 |          0 |   true |
| 2014-01-11T00:00:00Z |           56 |          0 |   true |
| 2014-01-12T00:00:00Z |           60 |          0 |   true |
| 2014-01-13T00:00:00Z |            0 |         20 |  false |
```

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` statement will solve this for you. And `OUTER APPLY` will solve the second requirement.

`APPLY`, `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY` as the most understood and under-utilized iterators in my opinion. But once you grasp their power and understand the use cases, they become lethal weapons in your toolbox. They are especially useful in `TOP(n) [by some logic]` situations, where there built-in functions fail to meet your requirements.

> Note the use of `BIT` to represent the boolean `TRUE/FALSE`

```
SELECT Day
     , RunningSpeed
     , PreviousRunningSpeed
     , CASE 
        WHEN RunningSpeed IS NULL AND PreviousRunningSpeed > 0 THEN 1
        WHEN RunningSpeed > 0 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
       END AS Status 
  FROM (SELECT Day
             , RunningSpeed  
             , d.RunningSpeed AS PreviousRunningSpeed            
          FROM tbl AS t1
               OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) 
                                   RunningSpeed
                              FROM tbl AS t2
                             WHERE RunningSpeed IS NOT NULL
                                   AND t2.Day < t1.Day
                             ORDER BY Day ASC)) AS d
```

Comment: getting the first part is easy and is like what you have mentioned if its> 0 we can put as true .but where i am facing difficulty is in the second part i.e if there is no data we have to go back and check if the last recorded code was 0

Comment: That part can be very simple as well. What is your platform? SQL Server?

Comment: But using lag you are specifying to go back only one  by setting the offset to 1.but we do not know if its only 1 day or more than that

Comment: You can `OUTER APPLY` if you're "previous" logic is more complex than what `LAG` can offer.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want for this is `LAG(IGNORE NULLS)` but SQL Server does not support that.

You can use a different trick, which is to get the maximum date where the status is 0 and the maximum date where the status is not 0 and compare them.  So:

```
select t.*,
       (case when statuscode = 0 then 'TRUE'
             when statuscode <> 0 then 'FALSE'
             when (max(case when statuscode = 0 then day end) over (order by day) >
                   coalesce(max(case when statuscode <> 0 day date end) over (order by day), '2000-01-01')
                  )
             then 'TRUE'
             else 'FALSE'
        end) as status
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e6e17c31fc3f64ab9e0369c722b93b43) is a db<>fiddle.

You can actually simplify this to just the last conditions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when (max(case when statuscode = 0 then day end) over (order by day) >
                   coalesce(max(case when statuscode <> 0 then day end) over (order by day), '2000-01-01')
                  )
             then 'TRUE'
             else 'FALSE'
        end) as status
from t;
```

The first version better follows the logic that you describe.

I cannot tell from the question whether you want to base the logic on `runningspeed` or `statuscode`.  The logic would be quite similar for `runningspeed`.